# UIActivityViewController's frame is getting set to zero

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm presenting a UIActivityViewController and the end result is nothing is being displayed.  The view is greyed out and during the presenting animation, you can see the Cancel button zoom up to the upper-left-hand corner of the screen, but then there's nothing.

Here's my code to present the view controller:

```
    NSString *textItem = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"wow this is cool!"];

    NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:textItem,nil];

    UIActivityViewController *activityVC =
    [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:items
                                      applicationActivities:nil];

    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = nil;
    activityVC.completionHandler = ^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed)
    {
    };

    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Via NSLog, I can see a subview of activityVC with the following info:

```
    <UIActivityListView: 0x22545920; frame = (0 0; 0 0); autoresize = W+H; autoresizesSubviews = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x22545c20>>
```

In my presentation if I recurse the subviews and look for a view with a frame equal to (0 0; 0 0), and then manually set the frame to, say the screen's bounds, then the activity view displays, however the cancel button doesn't show up and this seems hacked to begin with.  I've created sample projects with the exact code shown above and the activity view controller displays perfectly, so what gives?

Comment: show us the code of   `initWithActivityItems:applicationActivities:`

Comment: the third line of code shows this: `UIActivityViewController *activityVC =
    [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:items
                                      applicationActivities:nil];`

Comment: Do you use autolayout? In which view controller method do you call the lines above?

Comment: Yes, using autolayout.  And these lines are called within an action received on a button tap.  I have tested them within viewDidAppear: as well just for testing and in both cases I get this zero frame issue.  I went so far as comment out all code from my storyboard's initialViewController and add these lines to viewDidAppear: and I still have the same problem.

Comment: I have same issue but i cant understand how to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

finally i found solution...

its all about autolayout issue..

self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

Remove this line in whole project